How to shade areas between three cycles?
I am trying to draw some basic geometry pictures, as one of the examples, there are three identical circle as below, now I would like to fill the area ADB, BCE and ACF. I am trying to use buildcycle for arc AD, DB, BA, but it failed and returned nothing. Would you please help to check what's wrong with my code, and also please help to provide better solutions (by asymptote, not for tikz, I am trying hard to learn asymptote now). Thank you!
unitsize(3 cm);
pair A,B,C;
A=(0,0);B=(0.5,sqrt(3)/2);C=(1,0);
path pa=circle(A,1);
path pb=circle(B,1);
path pc=circle(C,1);
draw(pa);draw(pb);draw(pc);
dot(A);dot(B);dot(C);
label("A",A,W+0.2S);
label("B",B,N);
label("C",C,E+0.2S);
pair [] ab=intersectionpoints(pa,pb);
pair D=ab[0];
label("D",D,W+0.2N);
pair [] bc=intersectionpoints(pb,pc);
pair E=bc[0];
label("E",E,E);
pair [] ca=intersectionpoints(pc,pa);
pair F=ca[1];
label("F",F,S);
path p_ad=arc(B,1,240,180);
path p_db=arc(A,1,120,60);
path p_ba=arc(C,1,180,120);
path adb=buildcycle(p_ad,p_db,p_ba);
draw(adb,blue);  -- not work, no error
fill(adb, mediumgray);  -- not work and with error

Thank you a lot

For the definition of adb, use path adb=p_ad & p_db & reverse(p_ba) & cycle; rather than buildcycle.

The problem is that the arcs you define do not overlap -- the ends probably touch, but that's not good enough for buildcycle.   Try making them a bit longer, so instead of this:
path p_ad=arc(B,1,240,180);
path p_db=arc(A,1,120,60);
path p_ba=arc(C,1,180,120);

try this:
path p_ad=arc(B,1,250,170);  
path p_db=arc(A,1,130,50);   
path p_ba=arc(C,1,190,110);

Here is the complete source (with the output format set to PDF):
settings.outformat = "pdf";
unitsize(3 cm);
pair A,B,C; A=(0,0);B=(0.5,sqrt(3)/2);C=(1,0);

path pa=circle(A,1);
path pb=circle(B,1);
path pc=circle(C,1);

draw(pa);draw(pb);draw(pc);

dot(A);dot(B);dot(C);
label("A",A,W+0.2S);
label("B",B,N);
label("C",C,E+0.2S);

pair [] ab=intersectionpoints(pa,pb); pair D=ab[0]; label("D",D,W+0.2N);
pair [] bc=intersectionpoints(pb,pc); pair E=bc[0]; label("E",E,E);
pair [] ca=intersectionpoints(pc,pa); pair F=ca[1]; label("F",F,S);

path p_ad=arc(B,1,250,170);  
path p_db=arc(A,1,130,50);   
path p_ba=arc(C,1,190,110);  
path adb=buildcycle(p_ad,p_db,p_ba);
fill(adb, mediumgray); 
draw(adb,blue); 

if you compile this with asy you should get a PDF file that looks like this:


Thank you! Never thought the number is too precise to close the area. That's a good experience to share. Thank you!

I would like to share another solution which I have search this site yesterday, which I think has better solution than my previous solution. Here is the code:
unitsize(2 cm);
// import graph;
import patterns;
add("bengal",hatch(0.8mm,blue));

path a=circle((0,0),1);
path b=circle((1,0),1);
path c=circle((0.5,sqrt(3)/2),1);
draw(a);draw(b);draw(c);

fill(subpath(a,2/3,4/3)--subpath(c,2,8/3)--subpath(b,2,4/3)--cycle,pattern("bengal"));
fill(subpath(a,2/3,0)--subpath(c,-2/3,0)--subpath(b,2/3,4/3)--cycle,pattern("bengal"));
fill(subpath(a,-2/3,0)--subpath(c,-2/3,-4/3)--subpath(b,2,8/3)--cycle,pattern("bengal"));


Any better or more elegant solutions are welcome!

With tkz-elements and tkz-euclide or tkz-elements and ext.paths.arcto that I just discovered with this post Draw a circle with tikz cut by a square

With tkz-euclide and clips
The tricky part is the clips.



I start by coloring the entire circle \tkzFillCircle[h](A,B) I compile to see
I insert a first clip before \tkzClipCircle(C,A) I compile to see
And the last clip with out option \tkzClipCircle[out](B,A)

Code
% !TeX program = lualatex
\documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone}

\usepackage{tkz-elements}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\begin{document}
\begin{tkzelements}
  r=3
  --
  z.A = point: new (0, 0)
  z.B = point: new (r, 0)
  z.C = point: new (r/2,math.sqrt(3)*r/2)
  --
  C.a = circle: radius (z.A , r)
  C.b = circle: radius (z.B , r)
  C.c = circle: radius (z.C , r)
  --
  z.ab1,z.ab2 = intersection (C.a,C.b)
  z.ac1,z.ac2 = intersection (C.a,C.c)
  z.bc1,z.bc2 = intersection (C.b,C.c)
\end{tkzelements}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  [%
    h/.style={pattern color=blue,pattern=north east lines}
  ]
  \tkzGetNodes
  %
  \begin{scope}
    \tkzClipCircle(C,A)
    \tkzClipCircle[out](B,A)
    \tkzFillCircle[h](A,B)
  \end{scope}
  % \begin{scope}
  %   \tkzClipCircle(C,A)
  %   \tkzClipCircle[out](A,B)
  %   \tkzFillCircle[h](B,A)
  % \end{scope}
  % \begin{scope}
  %   \tkzClipCircle(B,A)
  %   \tkzClipCircle[out](C,A)
  %   \tkzFillCircle[h](A,B)
  % \end{scope}
  %     
  \tkzDrawCircle(A,B)
  \tkzDrawCircle(B,A)
  \tkzDrawCircle(C,A)
  %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
  %  comment in the final doc 
  \tkzDrawPoints(A,B,C,ab1,ab2,ac1,ac2,bc1,bc2)
  \tkzLabelPoints(ab1,ab2,ac1,ac2,bc1,bc2)
  \tkzLabelPoints[above](A,B,C)
  %
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}



with ext.paths.arcto library

Code
    % !TeX program = lualatex
    \documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone}

    \usepackage{tkz-elements}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{patterns}
    \usetikzlibrary{ext.paths.arcto}
    \begin{document}
    \begin{tkzelements}
    r=3
    --
    z.A = point: new (0, 0)
    z.B = point: new (r, 0)
    z.C = point: new (r/2,math.sqrt(3)*r/2)
    --
    C.a = circle: radius (z.A , r)
    C.b = circle: radius (z.B , r)
    C.c = circle: radius (z.C , r)
    --
    z.ab1,z.ab2 = intersection (C.a,C.b)
    z.ac1,z.ac2 = intersection (C.a,C.c)
    z.bc1,z.bc2 = intersection (C.b,C.c)
    \end{tkzelements}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
    [%
        h/.style={pattern color=blue,pattern=north east lines}
    ]
        \tkzGetNodes
        
        %https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/728745/draw-a-circle-with-tikz-cut-by-a-square
        \draw[h,radius=\tkzUseLua{r}] 
            (C) arc to (ac1) arc to (A) arc to[small,clockwise] (C);
        \draw[h,radius=\tkzUseLua{r}] 
            (B) arc to (bc1) arc to (C) arc to[small,clockwise] (B);
        \draw[h,radius=\tkzUseLua{r}] 
            (A) arc to (ab2) arc to (ac2) arc to[small,clockwise] (A);
        
        \foreach \c in {A,B,C}
            {%
                \draw (\c) circle[radius=\tkzUseLua{r}];
                \node[above] at (\c) {$\c$};
            }
        \foreach \c in {ab1,ab2,ac1,ac2,bc1,bc2}
            {%
                \node[below] at (\c) {$\c$};
            }
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}

