Draw a circle with tikz cut by a square
I'm trying to make an image of a circle with the center inside a square. But, when the circle is supposed to exit the square, it should follow the square shape instead. Do you happen to have any tips on how I can do this?
Here is a sketch of how it should look like


Welcome to TeX.SX! What did you try?

Take a look at the function clip.

In case you need to colour the clipped edges of the circle, have a at the intersections TikZ library

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz It's a shame that the intersection segments key of pgfplots comes with certain inaccuracies. Otherwise it would be a perfect choice here.

@JasperHabicht Actually one doesn't need intersections. One could draw a second square and clip it with a circle

\begin{tikzpicture} \draw[black] (-1,-0.8) rectangle (0.8,1); \begin{scope}   \clip (-1,-0.8) rectangle (0.8,1);   \draw[red] (0,0) circle[radius=1cm]; \end{scope} \begin{scope}   \clip (0,0) circle[radius=1cm];   \draw[red] (-1,-0.8) rectangle (0.8,1); \end{scope} \end{tikzpicture}

samcarter already gave a nice suggestion in the comments, however if you zoom into the drawing, you will notice that the clipped circle and the clipped square don't fit well. But you can avoid this by clipping away these problems ✂ (note that the thickness of the line is half the regular thickness due to clipping):
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \path[save path=\square, clip] (0,0) rectangle (4,4);
    \draw[use path=\square, thick];
    \path[save path=\circle, clip] (2.5,1.5) circle[radius=1.75cm];
    \draw[use path=\circle, red, thick];
    \draw[use path=\square, red, thick];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}




If you don't like clipping, you could also try the spath3 library:
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{spath3, intersections}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

    \draw[spath/save=square] (0,0) rectangle (4,4);
    \path[spath/save=circle] (2.5,1.5) circle[radius=1.75cm];

    \tikzset{
        spath/split at intersections={square}{circle},
        spath/get components of={square}\segmentsSquare,
        spath/get components of={circle}\segmentsCircle
    }
    
    \draw[red, 
        spath/insert={\getComponentOf{\segmentsSquare}{4}, reverse},
        spath/append={\getComponentOf{\segmentsCircle}{4}},
        spath/append={\getComponentOf{\segmentsSquare}{2}, reverse},
        spath/append={\getComponentOf{\segmentsCircle}{2}},
    ] -- cycle;

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}



more clipping seems to be the solution for all problems :)

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Just clip it away ... But I don't really like this solution. It would be much nicer to really re-draw the path. But this requires calculations and I am too tired for such things now ...

Note: With this method, only the inner part of the edges is visible...

@PaulGaborit Yes, this is what I mean with "half the regular thickness". I added another solution using the spath3 library which I like more.

To restore(double) line width, one can use line width/.expanded={2*\the\pgflinewidth} see answer by @Qrrbrbirlbel here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/671456/8650 and usage here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/671358/8650

Thanks @JasperHabicht! Both approaches work great

\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections, ext.paths.arcto}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[very thick]
\draw[name path=square] (-1.2,-0.8) rectangle +(2,2);
\path[name path=circle] (0,0) circle[radius=1];
\draw[orange, fill=gray!20, name intersections={of=square and circle}, radius=1] 
  (intersection-1) arc to[large] (intersection-3) --
  (intersection-4) arc to (intersection-2) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections, ext.paths.arcto}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[very thick]
\draw[name path=square] (-1.2,-0.5) rectangle +(2.5,2.5);
\path[name path=circle] (0,0) circle[radius=1];
\draw[orange, fill=gray!20, name intersections={of=square and circle}, radius=1] 
  (intersection-2) arc to[large] (intersection-1) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}



This is a much better approach than mine. I tend to forget these TikZ extensions …

Thanks, @hpekristiansen! This is an elegant solution. But what if the circle crosses only one side of the square? I am not able to get a proper arc in that case.

@Don: It makes no difference. -see edit.

You are right @hpekristiansen, I made a mistaken when I tried it. Thanks!
